# bIssue mounting NAS dd image

Tags: mount, nas, dd

I backed up my NAS HDD by using dd and now I am trying to mount the image in order to verify it. Using kpartx, I get following error:

```
# kpartx -av 2018-02-23_dlink_nas.img 
add map loop0p1 (253:0): 0 1060224 linear 7:0 64
device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p2 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop0p2
add map loop0p4 (253:1): 0 1024080 linear 7:0 1060288
```

whereas partition No. 2 contains the actual data. I assume this error is due to weird file system structure:

```
# file 2018-02-23_dlink_nas.img 
2018-02-23_dlink_nas.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x82, start-CHS (0x0,1,2), end-CHS (0x41,254,61), startsector 64, 1060224 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x81,190,14), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2084368, 3900393296 sectors; partition 4 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x44,41,48), end-CHS (0x85,254,59), startsector 1060288, 1024080 sectors
```

For the original HDD, I am able to mount it using mdadm, as the data partition is a linux_raid_partition.

Is there a way to still mount the image? It would be really great to have access to my data in case of data loss.

Update:

(1) Image size is 1,816,156,778,496 bytes

(2) Image size fits pretty well to the original HDD,

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6c640956

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1            64    1060287    1060224 517.7M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdd2       2084368 3902477663 3900393296   1.8T 83 Linux
/dev/sdd4       1060288    2084367    1024080   500M 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6c640956

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1            64    1060287    1060224 517.7M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdd2       2084368 3902477663 3900393296   1.8T 83 Linux
/dev/sdd4       1060288    2084367    1024080   500M 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

(3) The HDD is one of the RAID1 HDDs, i am able to mount it with

```
mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdc2
```

and then mounting `/dev/md0`

Comment: My answer is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your partition table and done some tests. This error you got:

> ```
> device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p2 failed: Invalid argument
> create/reload failed on loop0p2
> ```

may indicate your image is too small. Indeed, your partition 2 is the last one (the partitions are not in order) and it needs the image to have at least 3902477664 (= 2084368 + 3900393296) sectors of 512 B, i.e. at least 1,998,068,563,968 B. But…

> Image size is 1,816,156,778,496 bytes

It is obviously too small.

> Image size fits pretty well to the original HDD.

No, it does not. Either one of your disks has 2,000,398,934,016 B, which is enough to contain all the partitions. Proper image of the *whole* HDD should be of the same size.

The disk may have been only partially read by `dd` or the image has been truncated somehow, or it is by other means corrupted.